# React Native iOS Unrecognized font family 'Material Design Icons'

Tags: ios, react-native, material-design

I am building a mobile app with react native. The current app works fine on Android, but crashes on iOS.
This is the error that gives:

[image]

These are the dependencies that I am using:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^3.5.2",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.2",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.1",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.9.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^8.1.0"
  },
```

After some research, the community suggests to link some dependencies manually. Therefore, I linked `@react-native-community/datetimepicker, react-native-safe-area-context, react-native-vector-icons`. But they produced the following error:

[image]

Because I am using RN >= 0.60. So I unlinked them, then the `Unrecognized font family Material Design Icons` still persists. I did rebuild my app several times with `"npx pod-install"`, but no success. What should I do to get rid of the error and load `Material Design Icons` properly?

Answer (score 7):

```
import MaterialCommunityIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';
```

Call this function right after all imports and before your `<Component/>`

```
MaterialCommunityIcon.loadFont();
```

Usage in your `<Component/>` :

```
<MaterialCommunityIcon name="rocket" color="red" size={20} />
```

Comment: This solution worked well for me. I was getting the same error when trying to use a <Checkbox> from react-native-paper on iOS.

After importing MaterialCommunityIcon and calling  MaterialCommunityIcon.loadFont(), the problem was solved. No need to link any dependencies at all.

Comment: tried load at begin of App.js, same error. did not work for me. I have react native 0.68

Comment: well worked thanks